# Drupal is not executing my function MYTHEMENAME_menu_link inside of my template.php file

Tags: php, drupal

I have read a few other stackoverflow questions prior to submitting this but none had an answer that solved my problem. I am trying to alter the markup for the default menu output in Drupal 7, but the function I created named MYTHEMENAME_menu_link is not being executed for some reason. This is the function.

```
function lakestar_menu_link(array $variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
    $sub_menu = '';

    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']['mlid'];

    if ($element['#below']) {
        $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    }
    $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '">' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you clear the template cache?

Comment: Yeah I flushed all caches after each change to the function.